# Access Object created in another method C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview

In this code I'm creating Few DataGridViews. Number of those depends on file which within each launch of application will be different, so is number of DataGridViews.

How can I Access particular dataGridView `grid[i]` and modify it from which event `Form1_UserAddedRow` was called in that method?

Code:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\Base.txt");

    int diet_num = 0;
    int grid_num = 0;

    foreach (string x in lines) diet_num++;

    grid_num = (diet_num / Constant.DATAGRID_DIETS_IN_GRID) + 1;

    DataGridView[] grid = new DataGridView[grid_num];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid_num; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = new DataGridView();
        grid[i].Tag = i;
        grid[i].Parent = this;
        grid[i].Location = new Point(12, 12 + (8 + Constant.DATAGRID_ROW_HEIGHT * 2) * i);
        grid[i].Visible = true;
        grid[i].RowHeadersVisible = false;
        grid[i].Height = Constant.DATAGRID_ROW_HEIGHT * 2;
        grid[i].Width = Constant.DATAGRID_COLUMN_SIZE * Constant.DATAGRID_DIETS_IN_GRID + 3;
        grid[i].UserAddedRow += Form1_UserAddedRow;
    }
    this.Width = Constant.DATAGRID_COLUMN_SIZE * Constant.DATAGRID_DIETS_IN_GRID + 40;


    foreach (string x in lines)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        col.Width = Constant.DATAGRID_COLUMN_SIZE;

        col.HeaderText = x;
        int colIndex = grid[0].Columns.Add(col);
    }
}

private void Form1_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //I want to access grid[i] and modify it here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `DataGridViewRowEventArgs e` as the argument to your event handler and thus you can access the `Row` property like

```
e.Row.Cells["somename"].Value = "some_value";
```

Comment: But can I access whole datagridview?

Edit: Oh my, I can access datagridview through that row. Thanks alot, aprreciated :)

Comment: See above answer. You should be able to cast the 'sender' argument available in your event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast the Sender object parameter in your event handler to the type of DataGridView to retrieve the grid which has been effected.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGridView;
    if (grid == null) return;

    //... do something

}
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your request. I will do so in the future. Just omitted the context, because I was in a hurry and it is quite self-explaining.